# How to use multiple parameter in github action

Tags: github, azure-devops, github-actions

How can I use this parameter in GitHub action it is an input parameter from azure devops where the user has to choose the value before deploying

```
parameters:
  - name: environment
    displayName: CWP environment
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
      - Please select environment
      - dev
      - ts1
      - ts2
      - ts3
      - stg
      - prf
      - cte
      - tst

  - name: region
    displayName: CWP Region
    type: string
    default: central
    values:
      - central
      - east
      - both
```

Comment: That is Azure DevOps YAML pipeline syntax. What does this have to do with GitHub Actions?

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, I have no clue to use parameters in GitHub action I was trying to migrate the Azure DevOps to GitHub action. I tried with matrix in GitHub action but things not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manually run workflow in GitHub is a `workflow_dispatch` event triggered workflow. The `on.workflow_dispatch.inputs.<input_id>.options` field can be used to preset a selectable dropdown of allowed choices, if the `on.workflow_dispatch.inputs.<input_id>.type` is set to `choice` ([seen here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatchinputs)). The equivalent to your example would be;

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'CWP environment'
        required: true
        default: 'dev'
        type: choice
        options:
        - dev
        - ts1
        - ts2
        - ts3
        - stg
        - prf
        - cte
        - tst
      region:
        description: 'CWP Region'
        required: true
        default: 'central'
        type: choice
        options:
        - central
        - east
        - both
```

Comment: I don't think this is what was being asked. Clarification from the original poster is necessary before this question can be answered.

Comment: What do you think was being asked then? This is necessarily the only relevant answer to how to limit the possible input parameters to a pre-defined list, native to the platform; see the [action syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions) or [workflow syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) if you're unsure. Any other answer would have to either ignore the pre-set options as inputs, or construct an issue template to trigger a workflow that takes any input, and the issue limits it instead.

Comment: The syntax might have a broader set of use cases in azure devops, I'm sure you'd be aware of whatever they may be; but I'm not sure why you'd downvote an answer that is the only possible canonical answer for how to implement the same minimum example in the requested platform, using syntax native to the request platform.

Comment: I *have no idea* what was being asked, which is why I left a comment requesting clarification. The question as written is asking how to "use" a parameter from one platform in a different platform. You've decided to interpret it as a request to translate from Azure Pipelines to GitHub Actions, which may be correct. If it *were* correct, I still wouldn't answer it because Stack Overflow isn't a "write my code for me" service, I'd request that they include examples of what they've tried to do and what difficulties they were having with implementation.

Comment: The clarification requested, "What does this have to do with GitHub Actions?", was already answered by them in the question; "How can I use this parameter in GitHub action". There is already an overwhelmingly reasonable way to interpret the question. Additional clarification still has the potential to change how it's interpreted, but clarification is not necessary for there to be an interpretation that makes sufficient sense for it to be any more answerable than it already is. SO might not be a "write it for me" site, but examples that demonstrate the answer aren't not ordinary to include.